# How to move a window that's out of bounds?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to move windows that open up offscreen?](https://superuser.com/questions/53585/how-to-move-windows-that-open-up-offscreen)

I have dual monitors on my pc, that runs on Windows XP.  There is something wrong with my primary monitor port now so my primary monitor is not working.  The problem is that all windows open on the monitor so I can't change any settings.  How can I switch monitor settings if even the monitors window opens on the one I can't see?

Answer (score 6):

On the screen which does work, right click on the desktop and select properties (this will open the Display Properties).

If the display is on the faulty monitor side (ie, you can't see it), then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> (together), release both, press <kbd>M</kbd> and then use the cursor (arrow) keys (<kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd>) to move the window onto your working screen. You may only see a dotted line outlining the window. When you're finished, press <kbd>return</kbd> or <kbd>enter</kbd>

From here, you can select which Window to use (or not) under the settings tab.

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Comment: Once you've pressed an arrow key to move the window, you can also use the mouse to position the window and click when done, it's faster.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnected the primary monitor, then start your PC. Done. :)

( Windows will start up with **one** display and all windows will open on that display. )

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried that, it doesn't work.

Comment: That is weird. It worked on my XP laptop. I wonder what the difference is between the systems.  Anyway, can connect with VNC,RDP or similar from another computer. Would be a kludge, but that way you can change the settings.