# How to make an application remember the last place in multiple monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

In Windows 7 with multiple monitors, when you have some application open and you close or restart the computer, and you try to open it again, the application windows are not always in the same place that they were before.

Why does this happen? How can I fix the location of some application windows so that they always open in the same place on my monitors?

Comment: I think it depends on the application. Whoever wrote the application must implement that feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move windows that open up offscreen?](https://superuser.com/questions/53585/how-to-move-windows-that-open-up-offscreen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some programs need to minimize and maximize again to save the place, or close and open it. Don't work with all programs but with almost.

Comment: Don't it really don't work with all the programs, but its the answer until now

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on the design of the application however you can make most windows appear on one selected display, the way I do it is move the window to the screen, maximize it, then minimize it and maximise again and then close the window which then should launch on the same display.

Comment: It doesn't work that way for all the applications, but mostly apps has that feature.

Comment: Not worked. I'm testing it with Mozilla Thunderbird, and when I done this and restart the computer everything back to old place again.

Answer (score -2):

An old trick I have learned trough the years is use shift and then close it. That makes sure it remembers the spot where it has been closed so when you open it again its on the same spot!

Comment: However, this only works if the developer of the application implemented such a feature :), as I'm quite sure as of Windows 10, Microsoft has NOT implemented this feature on any global close window hook.