# Method to get windows left open on second monitor which is off back to primary monitor in Win7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, control-panel

I have a dual monitor setup, my primary and the second monitor is actually a large TV which is usually off. If windows are left open on the TV like windows explorer I have to turn the TV on to get it back on to my main monitor.

Is there any setting in Windows 7 that would let me right click an opened window in my task bar and have it sent back to my main monitor? This isn't about extending my task bar across to the other monitor. Just a simple right click option to send the windows back to this primary display, is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to move windows that open up offscreen?](http://superuser.com/questions/53585/how-to-move-windows-that-open-up-offscreen)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just found an answer while Googling here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f3040564-0457-4c91-af71-dce1bc673a99/moverecover-offscreen-window

It says...

> Windows 7 has a cool new feature that should help.  Click the icon in
>   the taskbar to ensure that the program has focus. Then hold down the
>   Windows key and press the right-arrow a few times. That should move
>   the window across your screens and eventually bring it back onto the
>   screen that is still active.

Comment: This is *so last decade* in any foss window manager :)

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин Hence why foss window managers are *so last decade* as a whole. ;)

Comment: While this works for regular application windows it doesn't work for dialog windows.  For example, I just tried this trick when opening a KeyPass2 database.  KeyPass2 opens a dialog box for the user to enter the master password for the database before it opens the main application.  The dialog stays stubbornly on the wrong (off) monitor.  Once I entered the password and clicked ok the main app opened and I was able to use this trick to move the main app window to the correct monitor.

Answer (score 19):

Pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> moves the current window across screens.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer for moving a dialog box, like the master password dialog displayed when opening a KeePass database.  Win + Arrow doesn't work on such a dialog, with or without pressing Alt + Space first.  Win + Shift + Arrow works perfectly, on both the dialog and normal application windows.

Answer (score 5):

@Anagio's solution is handy if you don't use the `Ease of Access Center` -> `Prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen` option. (This option is disabled by default.) But if that behavior annoys you (and consequently, you enable the option), then the <kbd>Win + Arrow</kbd> shortcut doesn't work.

So in that case, you can fix off-screen problems by giving focus to the desired application, then pressing <kbd>Alt + Space</kbd>, followed by <kbd>m</kbd>, to activate `Move`. Then you can use the arrow keys or mouse to move the window around. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or left-click to exit the move operation.

If your window is maximized, use <kbd>Alt + Space</kbd> , followed by <kbd>r</kbd>, to `Restore` to non-full-screen first.

Answer (score 3):

While the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> was the best solution for me, I found a very simple one to deal with this; and in my case it is mostly the secondary Monitor connected to my Laptop and the power goes off.

Just go to **Screen Resolution > Multiple Displays** and select **"Show Desktop only on 1"** (1 being your Primary display here).

Answer (score 2):

This works if the window is appearing off-screen

1) Hover over application on toolbar
2) Press Alt + Space or Shift + Alt + Space (if previous command is overwritten) 
3) Click on Maximize or Move

https://github.com/zeit/hyper/issues/1682