# Cmd.exe does not work from run

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe

I have Windows 10 pro insider preview build 11099.

The problem is that `cmd.exe` doesn't open a window when I start it from the `run`...  It starts a process as I can see in the task manager but I cant see it.

Even when I go to `C:\Windows\System32` and click on `cmd.exe` it is the same.

BUT when I search for `cmd` in the Windows menu it is working!

**A closer look on the Task Manager shows that when I start cmd from the Windows menu it starts a proccess under the `Apps` section, and from the `run` it starts a process under the `Background processes` / `Windows processes`**

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the cmd window isn't appearing off-screen?  See http://superuser.com/questions/53585/how-to-move-windows-that-open-up-offscreen

Comment: Yes I'm sure.  This is not what's going on.

Comment: If you roll back to the previous build, does CMD work as expected?  That's can be a problem with fast-ring, you're using a beta software package, so you may be hitting bugs that can't be fixed until the next version comes along.  Test the previous (or a stable) version, and if it works, then it's a bug in the new version.

Comment: Unfortunately the even happened  in the last build before I installed the update

Comment: Check the properties of the CMD link shown in the search window, and try entering that in Run.

Comment: The target of the CMD link is `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe`. even when I put that on the run it does not working... (When I click the link from the menu it works well)

Comment: I'd add `/D` switch (disable execution of AutoRun commands from registry) and some innocuous command, e.g. `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /D /K ver`.

Comment: What happens if you open a `cmd` prompt (from the menu), then enter `start cmd.exe` at the prompt? This is essentially (supposed to be) the same as launching `cmd.exe` from `run`, and normally it should open a second `cmd` prompt.

Comment: Not it is not the same. As in the question in bold one process is opened under the `Apps` sections (the cmd that I can see) and from the run it opens a process under the `background processes`. And starting `cmd.exe` with the `/D /K` flags didn't help.

Comment: Entering `start cmd.exe` from the command prompt didn't work.

Comment: `Entering start cmd.exe from the command prompt didn't work.` In what way did it not work - was there an error, did a second `cmd` process get started at all, did it (not) have its own console window, or ...?

Comment: It starts a new process under `background processes which I can't see its window`. No any errors.

Comment: If you ALT-TAB after `start cmd.exe`, how many `cmd` consoles do you get in the list - one or two?

Comment: Just one console

Comment: One last question... If you enter `start notepad.exe` at the same `cmd` prompt where you tried `start cmd.exe`, does Notepad open normally?

Comment: Yes, `start nodepad.exe` from the command prompt works well and open a notepad window. Not like when I type `start cmd.exe`

Comment: That's quite odd. I don't have any good guess at this point, but the previous q&a narrowed it down a bit and might help someone with a better crystal ball.

Comment: Try downloading [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx). Find `cmd.exe` in the list, then right click -> Properties -> Bring to Front. Does the window appear?

Comment: Preview versions are sure to contain bugs.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue with Windows 10 Build 11099. Process Explorer shows that is a child conhost.exe (a child of CMD.exe) is sitting around using about 20%. What is sad is that DropBox also fires of cmd.exe behind the scenes and it too is getting the same hanging behavior adding another 20% CPU usage.

Comment: Additional info: conhost.exe that runs behind Powershell.exe does NOT seem to exhibit the hanging behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many troubleshooting I tried to login with a diffrent user profile, and suddenly the `cmd.exe` worked from the `run`.

So I realized there is a problem (a bug maybe) with my currect user profile.
**I deleted my profile and the problem solved !**

Realy hope this will help someone with the same issue.

**How to delete user profile on Windows 10:**

To remove profile type `sysdm.cpl` in run and press enter to open System Properties.

When the `System Properties` opened go to `Advanced tab` and click `Setting` in `User Profiles` section to open it. Next select `Account Unknown` and hit **delete** button then hit Yes.