# Move off-screen window back to screen on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I just opened Wunderlist (the one from the Windows store) and the top half is off-screen. Right-clicking the icon in the task bar and selecting move no longer works, since it's not there. Accessing the move command in the menu bar through the keyboard [as suggested here](https://superuser.com/questions/53585/how-to-move-windows-that-open-up-offscreen) doesn't work.

How do I get it back on screen? (and why is this still an issue, so many years later?)

Comment: Screenshot plz?

Comment: Generally *Alt+Space then R* (restore) or *Alt + Space then X* (maximize) should bring things in focus.

Comment: Try Nirsoft's WinLister which is mentioned in the linked post. In WinLister, select the window you want to center and press Ctrl + F6. Or right-click the entry and click "Center Selected Windows".

Comment: So at work i have two monitors.  The window in question was in the right monitor when i left work (close laptop lid). Working from home today, the window would fly to the right.  Only thing that worked was Alt + Space then X (maximize) .. thx Jedi!

Comment: Alt+Space then M will let you move the window around using the arrow keys. That helped me get out of this situation. Also once you start moving with the arrow keys, you can continue moving with the mouse until you click the left button to release.

Comment: winlister is the best.. I tried the other tricks before, but this one works all of the time.. alt-space, etc. only works on some windows

Comment: For some reason nothing worked, but I solved it by changing monitor oriantation from landscape to portrait and back again.

Comment: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/winlister.html did help after some tinkering :)

Answer (score 63):

Sometimes it is impossible to right click the runaway window so none of the other solutions here work. The only foolproof method that I found ALWAYS helps is to find the process in task manager, click on the arrow to expand the application dropdown, then right-click the process and select "maximize window".

Comment: Selecting what, @Rup? :)

Comment: Woops, no idea why it truncated my last few words, sorry!

Comment: Do you not have a taskbar?

Comment: In Win 10 task manager, you may have to click a small arrow to expand the process and then right-click the lost window and maximize.

Comment: Hm, I don't have the "maximize window" option. [This](https://superuser.com/a/53590/64962) worked for me though.

Comment: In the current windows 10, there is no "maximize window" in the task list, via process, or in the start menu. For me.

Comment: @Peter and Brian, did you click on the arrow next to the app in the "processes" tab?

Comment: @foobarbecue yes, all I have as options is: End Task, Resource values, Debug, Create dump file, Go to details, Open file location, Search online, and Properties.

Comment: To get the maximize option, holding shift, click on the icon of the running application in your taskbar. You'll see the options for minimize, maximize, move, etc.

Comment: There are some extra smart apps (LogiTune, looking at you) which don't offer either of these options. Still looking, how to get that window to become visible... Maybe Window Explorer can help me.

Comment: I cannot find the "maximize window" option in Windows 10 task manager, too. A screenshot would be helpful.

Answer (score 15):

First activate the window by clicking on it on the taskbar and then press the Windows logo key on your keyboard together with the left or right arrow key.

If the window was minimized, you have to press Windows logo + arrow up key.

Comment: usually this works for me too.  But today it didn't :(

Comment: This did the trick for me. Application had no shift+right click menu (WinSCP). Held Windows Key and tapped <left> a few times and voila!

Comment: That's done the trick, as @SourceMatters said, sometimes need a couple of repeated <left> clicks.

Comment: Great option, the others did not work for me.

Comment: This only works for application windows that support window-snapping. This method doesn't work on Hyper-V virtual machine windows for some reason.

Comment: This does not work for me on Windows 2019 / Visual Studio Code

Comment: For me, I used windows left on a different window, then it shows the window selection on the right side, you can then use it to pull the target window over.

Answer (score 0):

Resizing the window from the bottom and dragging it to the edge of the screen to activate the snap function worked.