# How can I move windows from off-screen on a RDP session?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, window-manager

Using Windows 10, often when I disconnect my laptop from an external monitor some native windows will be stuck off-screen. I usually use Windows key+arrow keys to move them back. But this doesn't appear to work for RDP-wrapped windows. Closing the connection and reconnecting doesn't fix it either. Does anyone know how to get a window on-screen from RDP?

Comment: Does one of the solution here work: https://superuser.com/questions/53585/how-to-move-windows-that-open-up-offscreen

Comment: Just went through all of them and sadly no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any change to the desktop workspace area will cause Windows to move all
windows back into the visible workspace.

Some examples :

- Temporarily resizing the taskbar (unlocking it first as necessary).
- Displacing the taskbar
- Temporarily changing the desktop resolution.
  Right-click a blank area of the desktop, choose "Display settings",
  change the Resolution to another value, then choose Revert to undo.

Comment: Moving the taskbar to the left and then back to the bottom brought the window to the workspace. Thanks.

Comment: I had this problem but it was with a child window and thus did not have its own space on the taskbar, changing the desktopheight and desktopwidth  to 800 x 600 forced the window to (barely) on the remote desktop (hint: edit the RDP with notepad). When the display resolution was changed back to match the monitor(s) I use the window was sitting with its top left edge nicely at 800,0 (0 is the top of the desktop and increases down, counter intuitive I know but it's been that way as long as there's been graphics cards), from there I could grab and move as normal.